# Why Javascript menu doesn't show up on the properties for panel?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After I install the JavaScript Development Tools (1.6.100.v201410221502) on Platform: Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2). The Javascript menu doesn't show up on the Property for panel. (right click on a project on the project explorer panel and select property)

What is missing?

Comment: Is it a JavaScript Project? Or been Converted into one?

Comment: A part of the project contains javascript code - the front end portion.

Comment: I'm not asking if *you* think it's a JavaScript project, I'm asking if *Eclipse* thinks it is. Check the context menu of the project for a `Convert` submenu.